# ubuntu 12.04 long term monitoring

Tags: ubuntu, performance-monitoring

I´ve a Ubuntu 12.04 server with a lamp stack running.
I´m fighting with ressource scoring scripts (f.e. php scripts generating excel files).
I´ve googled a lot of software but couldn´t find a fitting solution.
I´m looking for a tool which can

- run 2-3 weeks as demon
- easy to use and install
- monitors server resources (CPU + memory)
- gives me after that a statistic which file produced which load at what time

thanks for help,

t book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend for single node monitoring that you try munin. You have to install both munin and munin-node packages. Munin is a server that collects data and munin-node is an agent that will take all the information about your servers performance and report it back to munin which will create nice graphs.

I don't know if a specific plugins are available for munin to monitor per-process cpu/ram usage, but it's easy to extend so you can write your own.

Comment: thanks, munin in combination with jjphp mempeak, https://code.google.com/p/php-mempeak/issues/detail?id=1 seems to give an insight. Rik, thanks for the links this is also really usefull!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking about process accounting.  It is part of the acct package on Ubuntu.

[Tecmint](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/) has an introductory article about using it.